# Bootstrap CSS transition not working

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

For some unknown reason, when I am trying to add a transition to a bootstrap dropdown, it won't work. But if I go through chrome developer tools, and manually turn opacity on/off it will go through the transition.

http://jsfiddle.net/mtkzrbn0/

```
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    transition: opacity 0.25s ease;
    opacity: 0;
}

.dropdown.open .dropdown-menu {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not combine transition with disblay: none, display: block (which bootstrap use when show dropdown menu);

So instead you set your element to visibility:hidden and switch it to visibility:visible when it opens.

```
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    transition: opacity 0.25s ease;
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.dropdown.open .dropdown-menu {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    height: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mtkzrbn0/1/